# How to center single image in the middle of the page using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Looks so simple, but so far I was not able to find a single answer to this.

The problem is simple, I have only one image, and I want to show this in the middle of the page and done.

Here is my code that works using only CSS:

```css
.centered {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      /* bring your own prefixes */
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }


And on my HTML code just this:
```

```html
<div class="centered">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
</div>
```

So far I have not found one single answer how to to this using Bootstrap 4, can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, just use 4 classes provided by the Bootstrap 4.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but still don't work, only align horizontal, but never in the middle of the page :/

Comment: @FelipeFlorencio Did you run the code snippet? It is actually center horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @FelipeFlorencio Are you using Bootstrap ver 4.0.0? Will you consider to use latest ver 4.5.0 because `vh-100` class is not available in ver 4.0.0

Comment: the code snippet shows it is at center horizonally and vertically both

Answer (score 0):

Use code as below

```css
html, body {height:100%}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center">
  <img class=" m-auto" src="smiling_face_emoji.png">
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Thanks mate, but still not working, never align in the center of the page it self only horizontal, it's so pit something that can be achieved so easily with CSS bootstrap make so weird

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a h-100 property to set height to 100% so make sure it is applied to your container and row.
No other css is necessary as Bootstrap4 has the classes needed to accomplish this by itself.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <img src="smiling_face_emoji.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No succes :D still pure CSS only I really was expecting something like this be much easier than CSS, but looking from in the internet, StackOverflow there's a thousand of request like this and nothing that I tried work, only simple CSS

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```css
html{
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
}
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="centered">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
    </div>
```

Comment: ok sorry. I read that incorrectly. my bad 

Comment: No problem thanks for helping anyway !